# Keep Getting A Different Output For My Created Array When Printing

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new here as well as new to coding. I got the piece of code and wanted to check if it word work. It pretty simple but since I'm new at this i'm having a lot of issues. I keep getting some random numbers when I try to output the array after calling the function. Would appreciate it if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
# include <stdio.h>    

int V[6]= {7,6,5,4,3,2};
int F(int G, int H) {
    int J;
    for (J=0;J<=5;J++) {
        if(G<V[J]<H)
            V[J]='Y';
        else 
            V[J]='N';           
    }
}

main () {
    int call;
    call = F(3,5);
    printf ("%d",call);
}
```

This is the code and my output is:

`4206608`

Comment: Your function  doesn't return anything, so undefined behavior. Compile with full warnings enabled and fix all of them.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Answer (score 1):

```
int F(int G, int H)
```

This first `int` means you are going to return an integer value from this function. But in your function, you are returning nothing. For this reason variable `call` is not assigned any value and showing garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the function not the array. By the way, it seems you forget to return value to your function, an undefined return value may cause you a random number.

Try to print this instead:

```
for (J=0;J<=5;J++){
    printf ("%d",V[J]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"You are printing the function not the array"`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So Thanks for the answers. Like i said i was new at this and it took me sometime to figure it out. 
Like the answers that i got suggested that i needed to return something which is why i got some random numbers.
So i changed the function to `void` instead of `int` and it seemed to work
I wanted to see if the function called changed the array to how i wanted it to and turned out it didn't so i had to change it a bit.

```
# include <stdio.h>


int V[6]= {7,6,5,4,3,2};
int J;
void F(int G, int H){
    for (J=0;J<=5;J++){
        if(G<V[J] && V[J]<H)
            V[J]='Y';
        else 
            V[J]='N';
    }

}

main (){
    F(3,5);
    for (J=0;J<=5;J++){
    printf ("%c",V[J]);
}
```

}

And i got the output that i required which was:

```
NNNYNN
```

Thanks for the support. Really appreciate it.